# Error compiling with inner class

Tags: java, oop

I have the following code:

```
public class Person{
    class Student extends Person{}
    public static void main(String[] ){
        Person p = new Student();
        //error compiling here, can't access non-static member from a static context
    }  
}
```

Please explain for me, thank for your help

Comment: Do you mean either "static member from non-static context" or "non-static member from static context"?

Comment: @Nambari looks like it, and its wrong =\

Comment: @hexafraction sorry non-static

Comment: @ThiepLV ***Which*** non-static? The first? Or the second?

Comment: error at  Person p = new Student();

Comment: @ThiepLV I know, but is it static reference in non-static context or non-static reference in static context? These two are complete opposites and mean very different things.

Comment: It is best to compile **exactly** the code you are going to post, and then copy-paste it and the error message into the question. Often, the people answering questions understand information in the error message that seems meaningless to the person asking the question.

Comment: it is non-static reference in static context

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan: Exactly. In some cases, we have seen the compiler error message so many times we know *exactly* what the issue is without even seeing the *code*.

Comment: @Jason Though in this case it seems to have worked the other way, at least for me. Not that OP should **ever** rely on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Student extends Person{}
```

is declared without `static` so we must have an instance of `Person` first.

When we are in `main` we are in a static context and have no instance of Person.

You should move the `Student` class to a *new* file called `Student.java` and actually make sure that when extending it actually does something.

You can then get an instance of it as attempted without worrying about inner types and nested classes.

Nested classes are used when one class needs to require that it's a child of an instance of another class. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Otherwise(and in most cases), classes ***always*** go in their own files.

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes must be given an instance of the enclosing class when created.

```
public class Person{
    class Student extends Person{}
    public static void main(String[] ){
        Person p = new Person().new Student();
    }  
}
```